# C#: Envio de dados para banco de dados (SqlCompact)

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Estou iniciando agora com C# devido a necessidade aonde trabalho, peguei um projeto até que estava fluindo, porém, estou com grande dificuldade para enviar os dados para o banco de dados (uma parte do código outra pessoa que fez).

`TotalRecordNum` seria o total de testes, sendo assim peguei os testes por bytes (`RecNum`, `Year`, `Month`, `Days`, `Hr`, `Min`, `EventBG`, `Bg` e `mid`) e depois passo via parâmetro para o banco de dados.

Coloquei um `if` comentado dentro do for aonde se eu determino o valor de `i` ele me traz somente o dados de acordo com o `id`(`TotalRecordNum`) e ele salvar normalmente, mas gostaria de salvar todos os dados.

Agradeço desde já, qualquer ajuda, dica, luz que me dere.

```cs
    public void RECRDecode(byte[] RECR_Buf)
      {
           
           int RecNum, Year, Month, Days, Hr, Min, EventBG, BG, mid;
    
           TotalRecordNum = RECR_Buf[0] * 256 + RECR_Buf[1];
    
           for (TotalRecordNum = 0; TotalRecordNum < 1152; TotalRecordNum++)
           {
               if (RECR_Buf[0 + TotalRecordNum * 8] == 0xFF)
                   break;
               if (RECR_Buf[1 + TotalRecordNum * 8] == 0x00)
                   break;
           }
    
           for (int i = 0; i < TotalRecordNum; i++)
           {             
       
               //if (i == 0)
               //{                
                   
                   RecNum = TotalRecordNum - i;
                   Year = (RECR_Buf[0 + i * 8] & 0xFE) >> 1;
                   Month = (RECR_Buf[0 + i * 8] & 0x01) << 3 | (RECR_Buf[1 + i * 8] & 0xE0) >> 5;
                   Days = RECR_Buf[1 + i * 8] & 0x1F;
                   Hr = (RECR_Buf[2 + i * 8] & 0xF8) >> 3;
                   Min = (RECR_Buf[2 + i * 8] & 0x07) << 3 | (RECR_Buf[3 + i * 8] & 0xE0) >> 5;
                   EventBG = (RECR_Buf[5 + i * 8] & 0x03) << 1 | (RECR_Buf[6 + i * 8] & 0x80) >> 7;
                   BG = (RECR_Buf[6 + i * 8] & 0x03) * 256 + RECR_Buf[7 + i * 8];
                   mid = Mid1_SN;
    
                   dadoGlicemia = BG.ToString("D2");
                   dadoData += Year.ToString("D2") + "/" + Month.ToString("D2") + "/" + Days.ToString("D2");
                   dadoHora += Hr.ToString("D2") + ":" + Min.ToString("D2");
                   AutoSN += MID1.ToString("D5") + mid.ToString("D5");
                   dadoID += RecNum.ToString("D2");
                   dadoEvento += EventBG.ToString("D1");
    
                   Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
                   paciente.NO += dadoID.ToString();
                   paciente.Glicemia += dadoGlicemia.ToString();
    
               //}              
           }
    
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendo mais simples possível!

Comece criando uma classe para estruturar as informações que você quer salvar:

```cs
public class REC
{
    public int RecNum { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public int Hr { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int EventBG { get; set; }
    public int BG { get; set; }
    public int mid { get; set; }
    public string dadoGlicemia { get; set; }
    public string dadoData { get; set; }
    public string dadoHora { get; set; }
    public string AutoSN { get; set; }
    public string dadoID { get; set; }
    public string dadoEvento { get; set; }
    public Paciente Paciente { get; set; }
}
```

Altere seu método de decodificação para garantir que ele retorne uma coleção de dados que serão salvos:

```cs
public List<REC> RECRDecode(byte[] RECR_Buf)
{    
    var dados = new List<REC>();

    TotalRecordNum = RECR_Buf[0] * 256 + RECR_Buf[1];

    for (TotalRecordNum = 0; TotalRecordNum < 1152; TotalRecordNum++)
    {
        if (RECR_Buf[0 + TotalRecordNum * 8] == 0xFF)
            break;
        if (RECR_Buf[1 + TotalRecordNum * 8] == 0x00)
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalRecordNum; i++)
    {             
        var rec = new REC();

        rec.RecNum = TotalRecordNum - i;
        rec.Year = (RECR_Buf[0 + i * 8] & 0xFE) >> 1;
        rec.Month = (RECR_Buf[0 + i * 8] & 0x01) << 3 | (RECR_Buf[1 + i * 8] & 0xE0) >> 5;
        rec.Days = RECR_Buf[1 + i * 8] & 0x1F;
        rec.Hr = (RECR_Buf[2 + i * 8] & 0xF8) >> 3;
        rec.Min = (RECR_Buf[2 + i * 8] & 0x07) << 3 | (RECR_Buf[3 + i * 8] & 0xE0) >> 5;
        rec.EventBG = (RECR_Buf[5 + i * 8] & 0x03) << 1 | (RECR_Buf[6 + i * 8] & 0x80) >> 7;
        rec.BG = (RECR_Buf[6 + i * 8] & 0x03) * 256 + RECR_Buf[7 + i * 8];
        rec.mid = Mid1_SN;

        rec.dadoGlicemia = BG.ToString("D2");
        rec.dadoData += Year.ToString("D2") + "/" + Month.ToString("D2") + "/" + Days.ToString("D2");
        rec.dadoHora += Hr.ToString("D2") + ":" + Min.ToString("D2");
        rec.AutoSN += MID1.ToString("D5") + mid.ToString("D5");
        rec.dadoID += RecNum.ToString("D2");
        rec.dadoEvento += EventBG.ToString("D1");

        Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
        paciente.NO += dadoID.ToString();
        paciente.Glicemia += dadoGlicemia.ToString();
        rec.Paciente = paciente;

        dados.Add(rec);
    }

    return dados;
}
```

Crie um método que irá receber a coleção de dados para inseri-los no banco de dados.

Esse método deve ser parecido com esse:

```cs
public int Salvar(List<REC> dados)
{
    var linhasSalvas = 0;
    
    using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("BancoDeDados.db"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (var dado in dados)
        {
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()){
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TABELA() VALUES()";
                linhasSalvas += cmd.ExecuteNoQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    return linhasSalvas;
}
```

Importante mencionar que pode ser que você precise instalar o pacote NuGet do Sqlite caso ainda não tenha feito. Também é necessário informar o nome do arquivo de banco dados e a instrução SQL para inserir os dados no banco.